# "Pensei que fosse" e "pensei que era" são ambos corretos e intercambiáveis?

Tags: diferenças, tempo-verbal

Vejamos as seguintes frases:

- "Pensei que o seu aniversário era hoje."  x   "Pensei que o seu aniversário fosse hoje."
- "Pensei que ela era sua irmã"  x "Pensei que ela fosse sua irmã."

Estão ambas as construções corretas?  Há alguma diferença semântica?  São perfeitamente intercambiáveis?  Bem aceitas em qualquer registro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As duas formas estão corretas. Um exemplo muito semelhante já foi discutido no Ciberdúvidas: '[«Pensei que fosse/era»: o modo das completivas selecionadas por verbos epistémicos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pensei-que-fosseera-o-modo-das-completivas-selecionadas-por-verbos-epistemicos/31116)':

> Enquanto verbos de orações completivas verbais de complemento/objeto direto — «que fosse», «que era», «que o filme era mais comprido», «que o filme fosse mais comprido» —, selecionadas por um *verbo epistémico* («Pensei»), a norma seleciona «o modo indicativo» (...) mas, por outro lado, também «é possível a ocorrência do modo conjuntivo mesmo quando a frase superior não é negativa (...) o que se pode observar através dos seguintes exemplos:
>
> «Os estudantes pensavam que podiam repetir a prova.»
>
> «Penso que ele ainda está na faculdade a esta hora.»
>
> «Penso que ele ainda esteja na faculdade a esta hora.»
>
> Portanto, uma vez que nos encontramos perante um caso «em que existe
> opção entre indicativo e conjuntivo, a seleção do modo conjuntivo
> exprime maior distância do locutor relativamente à verdade do conteúdo
> proposicional da frase completiva».

Ou seja, dito de outra forma: sempre que estamos presente uma *oração subordinada substantiva completiva de complemento/objeto direto*, isto é, orações do tipo:

1. O João sabe **que estamos à espera dele.** (O João sabe **isso**/**[-o]**).
2. Pensei **que ainda fossemos/íamos ao parque.** [Pensei **isso**/**[-o]**].
3. Achava **que o João fosse/era estudante.** [Achava **isso**/**[-o]**].

(caracterizadas pelo facto de a oração subordinante servir a função de objeto direto a um verbo transitivo e poder facilmente ser substituída por um pronome, como demonstrado nos exemplos acima), e em que, *na oração subordinante* é utilizado um *verbo epistémico* (saber, pensar, achar, acreditar,...), **tanto o uso do do modo indicativo (no seu exemplo, 'era') como do conjuntivo ('fosse') estão gramaticalmente corretos.**

A diferença, como destacado no link que referenciei, está no facto de o modo conjuntivo (como em 'fosse') exprimir maior distância do locutor em relação àquilo que é dito (pelo que pode ser considerado mais adequado, por exemplo, em contexto formal). Já o modo indicativo é muito mais usado em contexto de fala espontânea/casual.

Por isso, acho que a resposta à sua pergunta é mesmo a seguinte: ambas as formas são corretas, e o uso de uma ou outra dependerá sempre do contexto/registo de utilização. Num contexto mais formal, o modo conjuntivo será, por norma, o mais indicado.

**Nota:** A exceção é quando, apesar de ser utilizado um verbo epistémico (saber, pensar, achar,...), está presente na frase uma negação na oração subordinante, como referido no mesmo link:

> (...) A única situação, com os verbos epistémicos, «que pode determinar ocorrência obrigatória de conjuntivo na completiva» é quando há «a presença de negação frásica na frase superior» [oração subordinante], como se pode observar nos seguintes
> exemplos:
>
> «Não penso que ele chegue a tempo do jantar.»
>
> «Não penso que ele *chega a tempo do jantar.» (*agramatical)

Comment: Você poderia expandir sua resposta.  Uma resposta com mais detalhes, explicações e exemplos ?

Comment: Tudo o que expliquei está detalhado no link, mas, de qualquer forma, expandi a resposta